# Give a character string to define a file dependency in drake

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I am learning [drake](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) to define my analysis workflow but I have trouble getting data files as dependencies.

I use the function `file_in()` inside `drake_plan()` but it only works if I give the path to the file directly. If I give it with the `file.path()` function or with a variable storing that file path, it doesn't work.

## Examples:

```
# preparation
library(drake)

path.data <- "data"
dir.create(path.data)
write.csv(iris, file.path(path.data, "iris.csv"))
```

### Working plan:

```
# working plan
working_plan <-
  drake_plan(iris_data = read.csv(file_in("data/iris.csv")),
             strings_in_dots = "literals")
working_config <- make(working_plan)
vis_drake_graph(working_config)
```

This plan works fine, and the file `data/iris.csv` is considered as a dependency

[Working plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eERgH.png)

### Not working plan:

```
# not working
notworking_plan <-
  drake_plan(iris_data = read.csv(file_in(file.path(path.data, "iris.csv"))),
             strings_in_dots = "literals")
notworking_config <- make(notworking_plan)
vis_drake_graph(notworking_config)
```

Here it is trying to read the file `iris.csv` instead of `data/iris.csv`.

### Working but problem with dependency:

```
# working but "data/iris.csv" is not considered as a dependency
file.name <- file.path(path.data, "iris.csv")
notworking_plan <-
  drake_plan(iris_data = read.csv(file_in(file.name)),
             strings_in_dots = "literals")
notworking_config <- make(notworking_plan)
vis_drake_graph(notworking_config)
```

This last one works fine but the file is not considered a dependency, so drake doesn't re-run the plan if this file is changed.

[Not working drake plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaplS.png)

So, is there a way to tell drake file dependencies from variables?

Comment: Update: you may be interested in dynamic files: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/pull/1178. Brand new in development `drake` (the GitHub version, `remotes::install_github("ropensci/drake")).

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be a great feature :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [answer](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/347) from the developpers on Github, the code in `file_in()` is not evaluated so that's why it is not possible to use `file.path` in it.

Comment: One workaround might be `do.call`. A silly example: `library(paste0("MA","SS"))` fails, but `do.call(library, list(paste0("MA","SS")))` works. Not sure if that helps in your dependency tracking; never heard of drake.

Answer (score 5):

Per tidyeval, if you add `!!` in front of the `file.path()`, it will be evaluated and not quoted.

Also, in the new version of drake, the `strings_in_dots = "literals"` argument is deprecated.

```r
library(drake)
path.data <- "data"
dir.create(path.data)
write.csv(iris, file.path(path.data, "iris.csv"))

# now working
notworking_plan <-
  drake_plan(iris_data = read.csv(file_in(!!file.path(path.data, "iris.csv"))))
notworking_plan
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   target    command                           
#>   <chr>     <expr>                            
#> 1 iris_data read.csv(file_in("data/iris.csv"))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Great first contribution, Jeanette! Welcome to stackoverflow!